# Putting most accessed route first?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've read that Sinatra reads routes from top to bottom, meaning if a request matches 2 routes, the route defined first will be executed only, and the second ignored.

Does that mean that, as a request comes in, that Sinatra will look for the very first defined route, then the second, etc? If this is true, does that mean that putting the most accessed routes first will potentially improve performance (since there won't be unnecessary matches)?

Comment: Sure, it might, but unless you're experiencing actual performance problems you should assume that Sinatra's router is sufficiently optimized for your application.